# Cassandra Validation failed error - Repair session failed with error

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I'm running a Cassandra cluster with version 2.2.4. The cluster consists of 3 nodes.
When I start repair using nodetool repair command i got the following error. and further it is not proceeding.

```
root@ems:/opt/apache-cassandra-2.2.4/bin# ./nodetool repair
[2017-05-16 00:26:37,919] Starting repair command #47, repairing keyspace contexxio with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: true, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 768)
[2017-05-16 00:26:39,571] Repair completed successfully
[2017-05-16 00:26:39,574] Repair command #47 finished in 1 second
[2017-05-16 00:26:39,606] Starting repair command #48, repairing keyspace watchtower_keyspace with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: true, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 509)
[2017-05-16 00:26:40,555] Repair session dbbf6510-39ef-11e7-8027-d710f406f829 for range (-4631786651008530880,-4578496872070625882] failed with error [repair #dbbf6510-39ef-11e7-8027-d710f406f829 on watchtower_keyspace/release_stages, (-4631786651008530880,-4578496872070625882]] Validation failed in /10.128.133.99 (progress: 0%)
```

can any please one help me out of this .

Comment: To get a solution, check your error in system and debug logs and add it in your question. Also add the output "nodetool describecluster"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this.

Execute  `nodetool scrub` in the affected node. it solved the issue related to Cassandra Validation failed error.

Comment: Scrub worked for me, on some occasions where it didn't, I just restarted Cassandra process and ran repair without validation errors. Hopefully this helps people searching for the same issue

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure all nodes are up and ok.

2) Go to the node with specified IP (in the log you've attached, and check system and debug logs).

3) Make sure there is no other repair processes going on/stuck. To verify it, start with running **nodetool compactionstats** and **nodetool netstats** on all nodes. If possible, attach the outputs to the question.